# Create an object with specified indexes

Tags: jq

I am trying to use for loop for every object using jq. 
Sample Input generated by Elasticsearch

```
{
  "took": 202,
  "timed_out": false,
  "aggregations": {
    "aggsDateHistogram": {
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": 1465974236000,
          "search": {
            "value": 14
          }
        },
        {
          "key": 1465975137000,
          "search": {
            "value": 16
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I want to have an object that has a key value and corresponding value of value index from search.

```
{ "date": .aggregations.aggsDateHistogram.buckets[].key, "value": .aggregations.aggsDateHistogram.buckets[].search.value }
```

This gives me an object but with cartesian product, but I only want to have values like

```
key[1] : search[1].value
key[2] : search[2].value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to produce this output?

```
[
  {
    "key": 1465974236000,
    "value": 14
  },
  {
    "key": 1465975137000,
    "value": 16
  }
]
```

The following will do just that:

```
.aggregations[].buckets 
  | map({key: .key, value: .search.value})
```

And from a terminal:

```
jq '.aggregations[].buckets 
   | map({key: .key, value: .search.value})' input.json
```

Comment: This almost solved the problem, can you extend it to generate named indexes for result. Like
{
  key : 1465974236000 
  value : 14
}

Comment: @BilalAkbar So an array of objects? `[ {key: 111, value: 11 }, ...]`, just remove `| from_entries` and `| @text`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly simpler solution

```
[ .aggregations[].buckets[] | {key, value:.search.value} ]
```